# Route not defined php laravel5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I got an error  : Route [admin/news] not defined  I try to use @component in my create.blade.php

In my Controller I declare variable

```
public $route = 'admin/news' ;
```

In web.php

```
Route::post('admin/news/create', 'Admin\NewsController@store');
Route::resource('admin/news', 'Admin\NewsController');
```

In my html this return right Url

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ asset($route.'/create') }}">add</a>

<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('news.create') }}">add</a>
```

I check my route by using php artisan r:l

It has a `news.create`

I try to use other routes  both of these work fine not sure what's wrong with my create route

```
route('news.edit',$t->id)
route('news.destroy',$t->id)
```

**the problem is in my create.blade.php** I try to use @component by this

```
 @component('layouts.submitform',
              ['id'=>'create','method'=> isset($edit) ? 'PUT' : 'POST' ,'action'=> isset($data->id) ? asset($route.'/'.$data->id) : route($route)]
            )
```

Comment: Why are using it like that ? There is another way of defining route .

Comment: can you give me some example plese I use this way because It easy to make a many CRUD page

Comment: Route::post('news',['as'=>'news','uses'=>'UserController@news']);  also use 
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {    } for grouping your route

Comment: well I think the problem is not my route.php it in my create.blade.php

Comment: you want to create from tag ?

Comment: yes I try to change my route in to your way it still hot an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159632/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-test1321).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$route` set to `admin/news`. You say you want to go to the create page. You then say that the route is named `news.create`. So use `news.create` as the name when referencing it with the helper. Set `$route` to `news.create`.

You seem to want to use a URI and a route name. You have to decide which one you are going for.

[Laravel Docs - Routing - Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

[Laravel Docs - Helpers - Url Helpers - route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route)